# Merging Arduino Code C++ (NFC and Bluetooth)

Tags: c++, merge, arduino, bluetooth, nfc

I would like to merge two pieces of code and I'm not sure how I should go about it. The first code is for Bluetooth and the second is for an NFC reader. By simply just adding the script the bottom of the other it gives me the error `'Serial' does not name a type.` Although it runs perfectly fine on its own. They both need to be running at the same time as well. Any thoughts?

Bluetooth

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoBlue.h>

const unsigned long BAUD_RATE = 9600;

// The bluetooth tx and rx pins must be supported by software serial.
// Visit https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial for unsupported pins.
// Bluetooth TX -> Arduino D8
const int BLUETOOTH_TX = 8;
// Bluetooth RX -> Arduino D7
const int BLUETOOTH_RX = 7;

int prevThrottle = 49;
int prevSteering = 49;
int throttle, steering, sliderVal, button, sliderId;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(BLUETOOTH_TX, BLUETOOTH_RX);
ArduinoBlue phone(bluetooth); // pass reference of bluetooth object to ArduinoBlue constructor

// Setup code runs once after program starts.
void setup() {
    // Start serial communications.
    // The baud rate must be the same for both the serial and the bluetooth.
    Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    bluetooth.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("setup complete");
}

// Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop() {
    // ID of the button pressed pressed.
    button = phone.getButton();

    // Returns the text data sent from the phone.
    // After it returns the latest data, empty string "" is sent in subsequent.
    // calls until text data is sent again.
    String str = phone.getText();

    // Display button data whenever its pressed.
    if (button == 1) {
        Serial.print("Door Locked");
    }

        // Display button data whenever its pressed.
    if (button == 0) {
        Serial.print("Door Unlocked");
    }

}
```

NFC

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

// Number of known default keys (hard-coded)
// NOTE: Synchronize the NR_KNOWN_KEYS define with the defaultKeys[] array
#define NR_KNOWN_KEYS   8
// Known keys, see: https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/wiki/MifareClassicDefaultKeys
byte knownKeys[NR_KNOWN_KEYS][MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE] =  {
    {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, // FF FF FF FF FF FF = factory default
    {0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5}, // A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
    {0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5}, // B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
    {0x4d, 0x3a, 0x99, 0xc3, 0x51, 0xdd}, // 4D 3A 99 C3 51 DD
    {0x1a, 0x98, 0x2c, 0x7e, 0x45, 0x9a}, // 1A 98 2C 7E 45 9A
    {0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7}, // D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7
    {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff}, // AA BB CC DD EE FF
    {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}  // 00 00 00 00 00 00
};

/*
 * Initialize.
 */
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);            // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();                // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();         // Init MFRC522 card
    Serial.println(F("Try the most used default keys to print block 0 of a MIFARE PICC."));
}

/*
 * Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
 */
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

/*
 * Try using the PICC (the tag/card) with the given key to access block 0.
 * On success, it will show the key details, and dump the block data on Serial.
 *
 * @return true when the given key worked, false otherwise.
 */
bool try_key(MFRC522::MIFARE_Key *key)
{
    bool result = false;
    byte buffer[18];
    byte block = 0;
    MFRC522::StatusCode status;

    // Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return false;
    }

    // Read block
    byte byteCount = sizeof(buffer);
    status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer, &byteCount);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    }
    else {
        // Successful read
        result = true;
        Serial.print(F("Success with key:"));
        dump_byte_array((*key).keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
        Serial.println();
        // Dump block data
        Serial.print(F("Block ")); Serial.print(block); Serial.print(F(":"));
        dump_byte_array(buffer, 16);
        Serial.println();
    }
    Serial.println();

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
    return result;
}

/*
 * Main loop.
 */
void loop() {
    // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        return;

    // Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card)
    Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
    MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

    // Try the known default keys
    MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
    for (byte k = 0; k < NR_KNOWN_KEYS; k++) {
        // Copy the known key into the MIFARE_Key structure
        for (byte i = 0; i < MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE; i++) {
            key.keyByte[i] = knownKeys[k][i];
        }
        // Try the key
        if (try_key(&key)) {
            // Found and reported on the key and block,
            // no need to try other keys for this PICC
            break;
        }

        // http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/14316
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
            break;
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
            break;
    }
}
```

Merged Code (with error `'Serial' does not name a type.`)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ArduinoBlue.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

const unsigned long BAUD_RATE = 9600;

// The bluetooth tx and rx pins must be supported by software serial.
// Visit https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial for unsupported pins.
// Bluetooth TX -> Arduino D8
const int BLUETOOTH_TX = 8;
// Bluetooth RX -> Arduino D7
const int BLUETOOTH_RX = 7;

int prevThrottle = 49;
int prevSteering = 49;
int throttle, steering, sliderVal, button, sliderId;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(BLUETOOTH_TX, BLUETOOTH_RX);
ArduinoBlue phone(bluetooth); // pass reference of bluetooth object to ArduinoBlue constructor

// Setup code runs once after program starts.
void setup() {
    // Start serial communications.
    // The baud rate must be the same for both the serial and the bluetooth.
    Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    bluetooth.begin(BAUD_RATE);
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("setup complete");
}

// Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop() {
    // ID of the button pressed pressed.
    button = phone.getButton();

    // Returns the text data sent from the phone.
    // After it returns the latest data, empty string "" is sent in subsequent.
    // calls until text data is sent again.
    String str = phone.getText();

    // Display button data whenever its pressed.
    if (button == 1) {
        Serial.print("Door Locked");
    }

        // Display button data whenever its pressed.
    if (button == 0) {
        Serial.print("Door Unlocked");
    }

}

#define RST_PIN         9           // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN          10          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

// Number of known default keys (hard-coded)
// NOTE: Synchronize the NR_KNOWN_KEYS define with the defaultKeys[] array
#define NR_KNOWN_KEYS   8
// Known keys, see: https://code.google.com/p/mfcuk/wiki/MifareClassicDefaultKeys
byte knownKeys[NR_KNOWN_KEYS][MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE] =  {
    {0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff}, // FF FF FF FF FF FF = factory default
    {0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5}, // A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
    {0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5}, // B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5
    {0x4d, 0x3a, 0x99, 0xc3, 0x51, 0xdd}, // 4D 3A 99 C3 51 DD
    {0x1a, 0x98, 0x2c, 0x7e, 0x45, 0x9a}, // 1A 98 2C 7E 45 9A
    {0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7, 0xd3, 0xf7}, // D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7
    {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff}, // AA BB CC DD EE FF
    {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}  // 00 00 00 00 00 00
};

/*
 * Initialize.
 */

    Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialize serial communications with the PC
    while (!Serial);            // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
    SPI.begin();                // Init SPI bus
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();         // Init MFRC522 card
    Serial.println(F("Try the most used default keys to print block 0 of a MIFARE PICC."));
}

/*
 * Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
 */
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
    for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
        Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
    }
}

/*
 * Try using the PICC (the tag/card) with the given key to access block 0.
 * On success, it will show the key details, and dump the block data on Serial.
 *
 * @return true when the given key worked, false otherwise.
 */
bool try_key(MFRC522::MIFARE_Key *key)
{
    bool result = false;
    byte buffer[18];
    byte block = 0;
    MFRC522::StatusCode status;

    // Serial.println(F("Authenticating using key A..."));
    status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, block, key, &(mfrc522.uid));
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("PCD_Authenticate() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
        return false;
    }

    // Read block
    byte byteCount = sizeof(buffer);
    status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(block, buffer, &byteCount);
    if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
        // Serial.print(F("MIFARE_Read() failed: "));
        // Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    }
    else {
        // Successful read
        result = true;
        Serial.print(F("Success with key:"));
        dump_byte_array((*key).keyByte, MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE);
        Serial.println();
        // Dump block data
        Serial.print(F("Block ")); Serial.print(block); Serial.print(F(":"));
        dump_byte_array(buffer, 16);
        Serial.println();
    }
    Serial.println();

    mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();       // Halt PICC
    mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();  // Stop encryption on PCD
    return result;
}

void loop() {
    // Reset the loop if no new card present on the sensor/reader. This saves the entire process when idle.
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
        return;

    // Select one of the cards
    if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
        return;

    // Show some details of the PICC (that is: the tag/card)
    Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
    dump_byte_array(mfrc522.uid.uidByte, mfrc522.uid.size);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print(F("PICC type: "));
    MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = mfrc522.PICC_GetType(mfrc522.uid.sak);
    Serial.println(mfrc522.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

    // Try the known default keys
    MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
    for (byte k = 0; k < NR_KNOWN_KEYS; k++) {
        // Copy the known key into the MIFARE_Key structure
        for (byte i = 0; i < MFRC522::MF_KEY_SIZE; i++) {
            key.keyByte[i] = knownKeys[k][i];
        }
        // Try the key
        if (try_key(&key)) {
            // Found and reported on the key and block,
            // no need to try other keys for this PICC
            break;
        }

        // http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/14316
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
            break;
        if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the combined code that gives you the error. As it is I can only guess how you put the two .ino files together to create one Sketch.

Comment: I have added my version of the combined code.

Comment: When merging, there is only one `loop` as I know and only one `setup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appears because the following lines are not inside a function declaration. The compiler is expecting a variable declaration and instead sees the call to Serial.begin(). To fix that problem, move these lines into the setup() function from where they currently are:

```
Serial.begin(9600);         // Initialize serial communications with the PC
while (!Serial);            // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
SPI.begin();                // Init SPI bus
mfrc522.PCD_Init();         // Init MFRC522 card
Serial.println(F("Try the most used default keys to print block 0 of a MIFARE PICC."));
```

Of course, there should be only one Serial.begin() call in your setup() function, not two, and, as a commenter pointed out, you should merge the code from your two loop() functions into a single loop() function.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have fixed my code and it works great! Had to make some other tweaks but is all good. Thank you!